# How to find the minimum screen BufferWidth in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, screen-size

I can use $host.UI.RawUI.MaxPhysicalWindowSize.Width to get the maximum width (i.e. number of columns) for the PowerShell command window, and setting the size of the PowerShell command window is well documented, but the minimum buffer width seems to vary between machines. On one machine it was 13 but on another it was 14. I can set the minimum window height and width to 1 and the minimum buffer height can also be 1.

Does anyone know how I can obtain this minimum buffer width value programatically (without just trying values and catching the exceptions!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because setting `$host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize` affects the buffer of its console screen, (*Command Prompt -> Properties -> Layout -> Screen Buffer Size* is modified when you change `$host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize`), it has the same restrictions on its buffersize as the console screen.

As we can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686044%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the specified dimensions for the buffersize cannot be less than the minimum size allowed by the system. This minimum depends on the current font size for the console (selected by the user) and the SM_CXMIN and SM_CYMIN values returned by the [GetSystemMetrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

One implication of this, is that the larger your console screen font is, the smaller you can make the buffersize.

As an example: here's how to get the minimum width of a console screen. I'm P/Invoking the GetSystemMetrics function from User32.dll using [this advanced function](http://poshcode.org/1408) (New-PInvoke by Joel Bennett).

```
$SM_CXMIN =28 # "The minimum width of a window, in pixels." enum value
New-PInvoke -Library User32.dll -Signature "int GetSystemMetrics(uint Metric)"
GetSystemMetrics $SM_CXMIN # returns 132 on my system
```

To retrieve the size of the font used by the console screen buffer, try [GetConsoleFontSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683165%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from kernel32.dll.

**Note:**

The value returned by GetSystemMetrics $SM_CXMIN is the total width (including the borders) of the console screen.

Comment: Thanks for that. I had hoped I wouldn't have to get down to pixels and font sizes, but I guess that's the only way. If I try and implement this I'll report back, but in the mean time I'll just go with an arbitrary minimum width of 20

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post in my Google searches. The link for "New-PInvoke by Joel Bennett" provided by "jon Z" is long gone. Using the internet archive I found a single capture from back in 2015. For the sake of preservation here is the function.

```
function New-PInvoke
{
    <#
    .Synopsis
        Generate a powershell function alias to a Win32|C api function
    .Description
        Creates C# code to access a C function, and exposes it via a powershell function
    .Example
        New-PInvoke -Library User32.dll -Signature "int GetSystemMetrics(uint Metric)"
    .Parameter Library
        A C Library containing code to invoke
    .Parameter Signature
        The C# signature of the external method
    .Parameter OutputText
        If Set, retuns the source code for the pinvoke method.
        If not, compiles the type.
    #>
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
        HelpMessage="The C Library Containing the Function, i.e. User32")]
    [String]
    $Library,
   
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
        HelpMessage="The Signature of the Method, i.e.: int GetSystemMetrics(uint Metric)")]
    [String]
    $Signature,
   
    [Switch]
    $OutputText
    )
   
    process {
        if ($Library -notlike "*.dll*") {
            $Library+=".dll"
        }
        if ($signature -notlike "*;") {
            $Signature+=";"
        }
        if ($signature -notlike "public static extern*") {
            $signature = "public static extern $signature"
        }
       
        $name = $($signature -replace "^.*?\s(\w+)\(.*$",'$1')
       
        $MemberDefinition = "[DllImport(`"$Library`")]`n$Signature"
       
        if (-not $OutputText) {
            $type = Add-Type -PassThru -Name "PInvoke$(Get-Random)" -MemberDefinition $MemberDefinition
            iex "New-Item Function:Global:$name -Value { [$($type.FullName)]::$name.Invoke( `$args ) }"
        } else {
            $MemberDefinition
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm in wrong but with

```
[system.console]::BufferWidth
```

you get the actual buffer width size.

This value can't be less than the current `[System.Console]::WindowWidth` size (will throw an exception).

Comment: Yeah, the Buffer Width isn't the same as the physical screen width. The WindowWidth can't be larger than the BufferWidth, but what's the minimum BufferWidth if the WindowWidth is 1